# Изменение массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
$arr = array(
 [0] => array(
 'name' => 'Столы/Круглые/Большие',
 'products' => array(...)),
 [1] => array(
 'name' => 'Столы/Круглые/Маленькие',
 'products' => array(...)),
 [2] => array(
 'name' => 'Столы/Квадратные/Маленькие',
 'products' => array(...)),
 [3] => array(
 'name' => 'Столы/Квадратные/Большие',
 'products' => array(...)),
 [4] => array(
 'name' => 'Стулья/Мягкие/Со спинкой',
 'products' => array(...)),
 [5] => array(
 'name' => 'Стулья/Мягкие/Без спинки',
 'products' => array(...)),
 [6] => array(
 'name' => 'Стулья/Жесткие/Со спинкой',
 'products' => array(...)),
 [6] => array(
 'name' => 'Стулья/Табуретки',
 'products' => array(...)),
 .....
);
```

То есть массив, содержащий названия категорий различной вложенности товары. Надо получить из него

```
$arr = array(
    [0] => array(
    'name' => 'Столы',
    'products' => array(...),
    'subcats' => array(
        [0] => array (
            'name' => 'Круглые'
            'subcats' => array (
                [0] => array ( 
                    'name' => 'Большие',
                    'products' => array(...)),
                [1] => array ( 
                    'name' => 'Маленькие',
                    'products' => array(...)),),
        [1] => array (
            'name' => 'Квадратные'
            'subcats' => array (
                [0] => array ( 
                    'name' => 'Большие',
                    'products' => array(...)),
                [1] => array ( 
                    'name' => 'Маленькие',
                    'products' => array(...)),),),),)),

    [1] => array(
    'name' => 'Стулья',
    'products' => array(...),
    'subcats' => array(
        [0] => array (
            'name' => 'Мягкие',
            'products' => array(...),
            'subcats' => array (
                [0] => array ( 
                    'name' => 'Со спинкой',
                    'products' => array(...)),
                [1] => array ( 
                    'name'=> 'Без спинки',
                    'products' => array(...)),),
        [1] => array (
            'name' => 'Жесткие',
            'products' => array(...),
            'subcats' => array (
                [0] => array ( 
                    'name' => 'Со спинкой',
                    'products' => array(...)),),),
        [1] => array (
            'name' => 'Табуретки',
            'products' => array(...)),),)),

    ...
);
```

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Приведите свой код

Comment: @ArchDemon, я новичок и второй день уже пытаюсь такой массив сделать. так пишу кучу foreach и утыкаюсь в тупик. Не могу придумать алгоритм дейтсвий

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте эту функцию

```
function buildTree(array &$elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$element['id']] = $element;
            unset($elements[$element['id']]);
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я совсем ничего не понял, если можно, поясните чуть подробнее. Спасибо..

Comment: Читайте про древовидные массивы и рекурсию.

Answer (score 0):

Код за вас писать не буду, напишу лишь то, что может вам помочь.

Способ перебора массива [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php). Это поможет вам пройтись по изначальному массиву и поработать с каждым его элементом. Т.к. у вас многомерный массив, то, скорее всего, будут вложенные циклы.

[Рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F) поможет вам, если неизвестен уровень вложенности массива.

Функция [explode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) моможет вам разбить строку на массив по какому-то разделителю.
Пример:

```
$name = 'Столы/Круглые/Большие';
$names = explode('/', $name);
var_dump($names);
```

Результат:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Столы"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "Круглые"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "Большие"
}
```

Это, вроде бы, всё, что вам нужно знать, чтобы выполнить поставленную задачу.

Comment: спасибо.
Про foreach() и explode() я знаю.
К сожалению, мне не удается выработать правильный алгоритм действий.